# Как поправить расположение виджетов в контейнере?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Мой код заполняет виджетами цветной контейнер `box`. В него попадают следующие элементы:

1. `self.picture` - некоторое изображение с закругленными краями. Я получаю его с помощью класса `Label`
2. Три виджета `QLabel` - `self.label1`, `self.label2` и `self.another_label`(его делаю невидимым)
3. Две кнопки `self.btn` и `self.another_btn`(ее делаю невидимой)

Эти виджеты не выполняют прямых функций. Они нужны, чтобы можно было понять, как контейнер `box` располагает внутри себя элементы.

Контейнер `box` расположен в контейнере `main_box`. Туда же я поместил кнопку `remake_btn`, которая скрывает одни виджеты контейнера `box` и делает видимыми другие.

Первое нажатие скрывает `self.picture`, `self.label1`, `self.label2`, `self.btn`, но показывает `self.another_label` и `self.another_btn`.

Второе нажатие возвращает контейнер в прежнее состояние. Таким образом, у окна есть два состояния:

До нажатия на `remake_btn`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия на `remake_btn`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На втором скрине видно, что элементы `self.another_label` и `self.another_btn` притягиваются к нижней части контейнера. Думаю, что это происходит из-за того, что я использую метод `addStretch()`, отказаться от которого не могу. По мере наполнения `box` я несколько раз применяю данный метод к этому контейнеру. Нажатие на кнопку `remake_btn` скрывает виджеты, но не трогает пустые пространства, которые создает метод `addStretch()`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В зависимости от состояния окна, я бы хотел контролировать эти пустые пространства в контейнере `box`. Можно сказать, что мне нужно менять их количество, расположение и коэффициент их растяжения, при переходе от одного состояния окна к другому. Вот как примерно должен выглядеть контейнер `box` после нажатия на `remake_btn`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думаю, можно создать второй контейнер и скрывать не виджеты, а контейнеры. Но будет ли это рациональным способом? Звучит не очень хорошо. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как мне поправить расположение виджетов в контейнере `box`?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.x = x

        self.setMaximumSize(x, x)
        self.setMinimumSize(x, x)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture):
        target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(
            self.x, self.x, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation
        )

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(target)

        painter.end()
        target = None

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.index = 1

        main_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setStyleSheet('background: #7189DB;')
        container.setFixedWidth(250)
        container.setMinimumHeight(282)

        main_box.addWidget(container)

        remake_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Remake', clicked = self.remake)
        main_box.addWidget(remake_btn)

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container) # КОНТЕЙНЕР 'BOX'

        self.picture = Label('picture1.png', 150)
        box.addStretch(3)
        box.addWidget(self.picture, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text 1')
        box.addStretch(2)
        box.addWidget(self.label1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text 2')
        box.addStretch(1)
        box.addWidget(self.label2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        box.addStretch(2)
        box.addWidget(self.btn1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        box.addStretch(3)

        self.another_label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Another Text')
        self.another_label.hide()
        box.addWidget(self.another_label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.another_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Another Button')
        self.another_btn.hide()
        box.addWidget(self.another_btn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    def remake(self):
        if self.index == 1:
            self.picture.hide()
            self.label1.hide()
            self.label2.hide()
            self.btn1.hide()

            self.another_label.show()
            self.another_btn.show()

            self.index = 2
        else:
            self.picture.show()
            self.label1.show()
            self.label2.show()
            self.btn1.show()

            self.another_label.hide()
            self.another_btn.hide()

            self.index = 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что правильно создать второй контейнер

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.x = x

        self.setMaximumSize(x, x)
        self.setMinimumSize(x, x)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture):
        target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(
            self.x, self.x, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation
        )

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(target)

        painter.end()
        target = None

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.index = 1

        main_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.container.setStyleSheet('background: #7189DB;')
        self.container.setFixedWidth(250)
        self.container.setMinimumHeight(282)

        main_box.addWidget(self.container)

#        remake_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Remake', clicked = self.remake)
#        main_box.addWidget(remake_btn)

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.container)                            # КОНТЕЙНЕР 'BOX'

        self.picture = Label('im.png', 150)
        box.addStretch(3)
        box.addWidget(self.picture, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text 1')
        box.addStretch(2)
        box.addWidget(self.label1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text 2')
        box.addStretch(1)
        box.addWidget(self.label2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        box.addStretch(2)
        box.addWidget(self.btn1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        box.addStretch(3)

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

        self.container_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.container_2.setStyleSheet('background: #7189DB;')
        self.container_2.setFixedWidth(250)
        box_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.container_2)                            # КОНТЕЙНЕР 'box_2'
        box_2.addStretch(3)
        self.another_label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Another Text')                    
        box_2.addWidget(self.another_label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        box_2.addStretch(1)
        self.another_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Another Button')                
        box_2.addWidget(self.another_btn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        box_2.addStretch(3)
        main_box.addWidget(self.container_2)
        self.container_2.hide()

        remake_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Remake', clicked = self.remake)
        main_box.addWidget(remake_btn)
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def remake(self):
        if self.index == 1:
            '''
            self.picture.hide()
            self.label1.hide()
            self.label2.hide()
            self.btn1.hide()
            self.another_label.show()
            self.another_btn.show()
            '''
            self.container.hide()
            self.container_2.show()

            self.index = 2
        else:
            '''
            self.picture.show()
            self.label1.show()
            self.label2.show()
            self.btn1.show()
            self.another_label.hide()
            self.another_btn.hide()
            '''
            self.container_2.hide()
            self.container.show()

            self.index = 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое. Почему-то я подумал, что есть более правильный способ :)

Comment: @MAXIM045 Зачем вы убрали последний вопрос? Вы  бы могли сделать Update. Я потратил какое-то количество времени, чтобы предложить вам вариант решения. Опубликуйте вопрос, иначе я потратил время зря.

Comment: Я обдумал в голове некоторые моменты и понял, что мой вопрос задан неверно. Мне нужно полностью перерисовать схему и переписать весь текст. Я понимал, что на это уйдет очень много времени, которого, сейчас у меня, к сожалению, нет. Я решил посмотреть последнее время вашей активности на сайте, и, т.к вас не было достаточно давно, решил, что вы тоже сочли мой вопрос неуместным. Могу ли я задать новый вопрос, но по этой же проблеме завтра? Прошу прощения, что так получилось :(

Comment: @MAXIM045 вы можете просто восстановить удаленный вопрос. Может вам и не придется задавать следующий вопрос.

Comment: Я восстановил вопрос. Еще раз прошу прощения, хотел сделать как лучше, а получилось как всегда :(